# Convex subsets of $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I have some troubles with proving that $A$ and $B$ are convex.

$A = \left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,:\, y > \frac{1}{|x|}, x<0\right\} \quad \mbox{and}\quad B = \left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,:\, y > \frac{1}{x}, x>0\right\}$.

The definition of convex is:
A set A is convex iff for $a,b\in A$ and $\alpha\in[1,0]$, then $\alpha a+(1−\alpha)b\in A$.

I have some troubles with proving that $A$ and $B$ are convex.
My attempt for $A$ (I think that $B$ should be the same idea)

Let $a=(a_1,a_2),b=(b_1,b_2)\in A$, and $\alpha \in (0,1)$, its clear that

$$\alpha a_1+(1-\alpha)b_1<0.$$

On the other hand, we know that

$$b_2> \frac{1}{|b_1|} \quad \mbox{and} \quad a_2> \frac{1}{|a_1|} $$

How can I arrange the inequalities? Any hint?

Comment: Do you recall the definition of convexity? / what definition are you working with?

Comment: Hi@frogeyedpeas usual definition in $\mathbb{R^2}$. A set $A$ is convex iff for $a,b\in A$ and $\alpha\in [1,0]$, $\alpha a + (1-\alpha)b\in A$.

Comment: yep thats a good working definition, so given that definition can you edit your question statement and articulate where you get stuck?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Ok

Comment: Ok perfect, so now you still have to do the following. Given the points q = (a1, a2) and p = (b1, b2), we wrote that we want to check if $\alpha q + (1-\alpha)p$ is in the set A for any alpha. Write out that inequality involving a1,a2, b1, b2 explicitly. Hint: This should give you an inequality involving (a1, a2) and (b1, b2) which combined the alpha formula for congexity with the definition of the set A which is, any point (x,y) is in the set A if; (y > 1/x).

Comment: Add that to your work

Comment: Do you know the rules that characterize convex/concave functions in terms of the sign of the second derivative?

Comment: @RobArthan Acutally, no. Could you suggest me some bibliography?

Comment: See the discussion of twice differentiable functions in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function. But if you have been set this problem without being taught that theory, you are presumably being asked to prove convexity from first principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, prove that the function $f:\left]-\infty,0\right[$ such that $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|}=\frac{1}{-x}$ is a convex function (by the 2nd derivative criterion), with that, you have, for all $x_1,x_2\in \left]-\infty,0\right[$ and $\alpha\in[0,1]$:
$$f(\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha)x_2)\leq \alpha f(x_1)+(1-\alpha)f(x_2),$$
that is
$$\frac{1}{|\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha)x_2|}\leq \alpha \frac{1}{|x_1|}+(1-\alpha)\frac{1}{|x_2|}.$$
Now, since
$$b_2> \frac{1}{|b_1|} \quad \mbox{and} \quad a_2> \frac{1}{|a_1|}$$
you can get
$$\alpha a_2 +(1-\alpha)b_2 > \alpha \frac{1}{|a_1|}+(1-\alpha)\frac{1}{|b_1|}\geq \frac{1}{|\alpha a_1+(1-\alpha)b_1|},$$
therefore $\alpha a+(1−\alpha)b\in A.$